# Verifying maxima/minima in Lagrange multipliers method

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Ques : maximize $$F=xy+\pi x^2/8+k(2y+x+\pi x/2 - 40)$$
I tried solving it using Lagrange multiplier method to get the answer $$(x,y)=(80/(\pi+4),40/(\pi+4))$$ which is correct as per book solution. I was trying to verify whether it corresponds to maximum or minimum value. So,

$$F_{xx}=\pi /4$$
$$F_{yy}=0$$
$$F_{xy}=1$$

Now $$F_{xx}F_{yy}-F_{xy}^2 < 0$$ This means $(x,y)=(80/(\pi+4),40/(\pi+4))$ is neither maximum nor minimum.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales.$2y+x+\pi x/2=0$ I guess

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Right. I should not do this on my netbook--the $k$ looks like an $x$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I updated the equation.

Comment: The second derivative test tells you something about the function at its critical points. The critical point is at the origin.

Comment: At $(x,y)=(80/(\pi+4),40/(\pi+4))$ , $F_x=0, F_y=0$. Then why is it not a critical point?

Answer (score 1):

Along the line

$$\left(1+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)x+2y=40$$

the function

$$ f(x,y)=xy+\frac{\pi}{8}x^2 $$

reduces to

$$ f(x)=20x-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)x^2 $$

which attains a maximum value at $x=\dfrac{80}{4+\pi}$

The second derivative test would be appropriate if one were determining the nature of the critical points of $f(x,y)$. [which is at $(0,0)$.]

Comment: I solved this way but fail to understand why is it not working using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: It worked using Lagrange multipliers. But you cannot use the second derivative test to decide whether it is a maximum or minimum there. You have to use some other method to decide that, such as evaluating the value of $f$ (not $F$) at the point found. In this case, $f$ has a value of $800/(4+\pi)$ at that point. Pick any other point on the given line and you will see that $f$ has a smaller value. So the point you found using Lagrange multipliers is where $f$ has a maximum, not where it has a minimum.

Comment: I appreciate your help but still my question hasn't been answered. Why can't I apply 2nd derivative test here? I have applied it in many other questions successfully but why not here?

Comment: In the other cases it had to have been an accident.